# ¿Como puedo crear un metodo que construya diferentes objetos en funcion de una variable?

Tags: php, poo, patrones-de-diseño

Tengo varios modelos:

```
class ModeloA {
    public function __construct(){} 
}

class ModeloB {
    public function __construct($param1, $param2){} 
}
```

Y un controlador al que inyecto los modelos:

```
$controller = new Controller($modelInstance);
```

Necesito determinar cual de los modelos le voy a pasar al controlador y para ello necesito una funcion que sea capaz de construir un objeto ModeloA o ModeloB en función de una variable, dicha variable sería el nombre del controlador ($controllerName):

```
public function modelBuilder($controllerName) {
   // Construir objeto ModeloA o ModeloB en funcion de $controllerName
}

  // Para luego poder hacer
 $controller = new $controllerName($modelInstance);
```

Comment: Si vas a tener más de un controlador y el modelo a instanciar depende del controlador que tienes que instanciar, ¿por qué no instanciar el modelo en el constructor del controlador?

Comment: He tratado de seguir los principios SOLID a la hora de crear las clases , entonces al aplicar la inversión de dependencias inyecto a los controladores el modelo en vez de crearlos en su constructor. Es cierto que podria instanciar los modelos en el constructor del propio controlador pero  ¿No seria eso un mal diseño? @ErnestoRM

Comment: Sí, sería un mal diseño. Entonces ¿necesitas una función que dado el nombre de un un controlador te instancie un modelo para pasarle a ese controlador?

Comment: Exacto , el contexto de todo esto es un controlador frontal en el que yo recibo el nombre del controlador que voy a necesitar y ese controlador a su vez va a necesitar inyectar su modelo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si te servirá algo así:

```
class modelo_X
{

    public $mensaje;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mensaje = 'Modelo: modelo_X';
    }
}


class modelo_Y
{
    public $mensaje;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mensaje = 'Modelo: modelo_Y';
    }
}

class controller
{
    public $modelo;

    public function __construct($modelo)
    {
        $this->modelo = $modelo;
    }

}

class controlador_X extends controller
{

    public function __construct($modelo)
    {
        parent::__construct($modelo);
        echo $this->modelo->mensaje;
    }
}

class controlador_Y extends controller
{

    public function __construct($modelo)
    {
        parent::__construct($modelo);
        echo $this->modelo->mensaje;
    }
}

function modelBuilder($nombreControlador)
{

    $dic = [
        'controlador_X' => 'modelo_X',
        'controlador_Y' => 'modelo_Y',

    ];

    return new $dic[$nombreControlador];
}

$nombreControlador = 'controlador_X';
$modelo = modelBuilder($nombreControlador);
$controller = new $nombreControlador($modelo);

echo '<br>';

$nombreControlador = 'controlador_Y';
$modelo = modelBuilder($nombreControlador);
$controller = new $nombreControlador($modelo);
echo '<br>';
```

> Modelo: modelo_X
>
> Modelo: modelo_Y

Simplemente, dado un nombre de controlador, instancia el modelo que se le ha asgnado en el array asociativo que funciona a modo de diccionario.

Comment: Creo que es justo lo que necesitaba voy a intentar aplicarlo y dare la respuesta por valida.